# How to add custom stylesheets to magento2 Wysiwyg editor

Tags: magento2.2, wysiwyg

How do i add styles to the admin so that when i enter content into the wysiwyg and save i can see a preview of what it will look like on the fronted in the wysiwyg

Comment: I'm not sure i understand, you want to add styles to the wyswiyg when entering content or you want to style wysiwyg content on the frontend after its been entered?

Comment: I need to view the exact styles of the tags within the editor after saving, which I get in the frontend view.